# Curl not showing any errors or output

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, tor

Im trying to fetch the source of a wordpress post, then look in the source and grab a specific string of text, lets say the post date. I am using tor as the wordpress blog is blocked on my end. Right now it doesnt display any errors and doesnt display anything in terminal. Its a valid website and doesnt block Tor or anything like that. There are no errors displayed in terminal or in PHPs error log, and Ive run out of places to look for errors, anybody have an idea why its doing this? Curl works properly in another instance to correctly fetch a websites source. (Also the variable tport is the correct port on this machine, 9150)

```
$url = 'http://subdomain.domain.com/2015/02/01/page/'; $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "udp://127.0.0.1:$tport/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
$output = curl_exec($ch); echo $output;
echo curl_error($ch); curl_close($ch);
```

EDIT: Header information. What makes it a bad request?

```
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 9150 (#1)
 HTTP/1.115/02/01/page/
Host: subdomain.domain.com
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
* Server nginx is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx
< Date: Wed, 05 Aug 2015 22:44:12 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 1245
< Connection: close
< ETag: "53f497d2-4dd"
< X-ac: 1.fra _dca
<
* Closing connection 1
Connected to host successfully
```

Comment: get header information as well, is it giving any status codes?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with your code that would cause it to issue bad requests.  I tried your exact code with another site and it worked fine.  Perhaps they are saying bad request because of some missing header information (like User-Agent which lots of sites require).